# что нужно знать чтобы писать программы с графическим интерфейсом на Си?

Tags: linux, c, gui, xlib

Проблема такая - изучил основы Си. Написал кое какие программы консольного формата которые ныне решают мои задачи. Но теперь мне понадобилась программа с графическим интерфейсом поскольку меня заинтересовала работа с изображениями, а консоль тут даже отдаленно ничем помочь не может.

Интересно именно под `linux` с использованием `xlib` : я уже пытался понять с чего начать, но кроме [этого](http://rus-linux.net/MyLDP/BOOKS/Linux-tools/GUI_01.html) ничего вразумляющего не нашел, и даже тут сразу столкнулся с системными переменными.
Сразу после этого море вопросов по типу: 1) а что это?
2) а где их брать?
3) а как понять за что какая отвечает?
4) а какие у них есть свойства?
и т. д.

И как я понимаю это наверняка не единственное что необходимо знать, чтобы писать подобные программы.

Прошу тех кто уже занимается подобным - очень нужен какой-нибудь гайд или своего рода `roadmap` - просто очень многие вещи которые гуглишь на эту тему либо бесполезны(не по теме в итоге) либо есть нужное но для их понимания надо еще что-то знать - как в случае с системными переменными(в том смысле что - а с чего начать изучать эти системные переменные  и т. д. Ведь все постигается на практике)

Заранее спасибо))

Comment: *"именно под linux с использованием xlib"* - месье знает толк

Comment: если на C, то наверное лучше использовать SDL и/или GTK, xlib это по нынешним временам, как ассемблер

Comment: http://davesource.com/Fringe/Fringe/Computers/Languages/tcl_tk/tcl_C.html

Comment: ncurses и TUI уже пробовали?

Comment: Посмотрите на [встраивание tcl/tk в C](https://wiki.tcl-lang.org/page/Adding+Tcl%2FTk+to+a+C+application). Если же хотите писать прямо на Xlib, то читайте результаты запроса в гугл `xlib programming manual` (сразу скажу, в этом случае придется прочесть минимум сотни страниц доки, прежде чем удастся  написать какое-то свое первое простенькое окошко)

Comment: Если вот прям Си и гуй - это GTK+.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если речь о современном и хорошо [документированном, то GTK3](https://docs.gtk.org/gtk3/getting_started.html) или [GTK4 если обновили систему](https://docs.gtk.org/gtk4/getting_started.html) хорошо интегрируется с голым си без плюсов: без классов. Сигналы реализованны колбэками.

[WxWidgets](https://ru.wikibooks.org/wiki/%D0%A3%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B8_wxSmith:_Hello_world) если ГТК покажется сложным. Но тут уже плюсы.

Для винды оно тоже собирается, но тяжелее чем Qt.

Qt для кода на плюсах имеет довольно много возможностей. Интересные интерфейсы получаются в связке с QML.

Примитивами xlib  никто уже не пишет ничего серьёзного. Разве что утилиту настройки тач стекла можно встретить.

Answer (score 1):

Начинать надо с чего попроще. SFML например.

Answer (score -2):

Для Linux/OSX использую обычно Qt, он достаточно простой и понятный.

Для Windows по хорошему конечно WinAPI! Но я очень ленивый поэтому использую C++ Builder с VCL. Кстати скажу что в VCL из коробки очень удобный набор для работы с картинками.

Comment: Реклама !!!! :)))))

Comment: Или пиратство, зависит уже от читающего)))  Что то, что то конечно платный тулкит, по крайней мере без лишнего подгорания 5й точки. Вообще в Си и С++  - GUI это боль слёзы и страдания..

Comment: Вопрос был про разработку на С.

Comment: @user7860670 А что с каких-то пор кьют не компилируется с Си кодом? Или винапи не работает с Си? Вы сначала разберитесь в вопросе...

Comment: @EugeneX Qt вроде никогда не компилировался с С кодом, даже ранние версии в 90-х уже предоставляли С++ интерфейс. И крайне странно писать о Qt "достаточно простой и понятный".  WinAPI из С можно использовать только номинально. А упомянутый VCL вообще когда-о был движущей силой С++ билдера.

Comment: @user7860670 но ваш си код легко завернутся в библиотеку или сишный файл, который с легкостью слинкуется в с классами кутэ